# Asp.Net Core WebApi: Authorize attribute Error 403

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization

I work in **Asp.Net Core WebApi** project and created a role *"admin"* and add it to my user. But if I logged in as an admin, the first method will return *"This is admin!"*, but the second method returns an error 403 Forbidden.

If I remove the Roles parameter from the Authorize attribute, everything will go fine. I do not understand why I can not access the second method because my user has an admin role.

```
// Host/api/roles/getroles
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetRoles()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            bool isAdmin = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, Roles.AdminRole);               
            if (isAdmin)
                return new[] {"This is admin!"};

            return await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }


        // ===== Admin Methods =====

        // Host/api/roles/createrole
        [Authorize(Roles = Roles.AdminRole)]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole([FromBody] CreateRoleViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(model.RoleName));

            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return BadRequest(result);

            return Ok();
        }
```

In the request for the second method I send:

*Headers:
    content-type:application/json
    authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJh...*

*Body:
    RoleName = "Programmer"*

Maybe I need to add something to the Headers?

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // ===== Add DbContext ========
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            // ===== Add Identity ========
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole> (opts=> {
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                }) 
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    cfg.SaveToken = true;
                    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidIssuer   = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),

                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                    };
                });

            // ===== Add MVC =====
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app,
            IHostingEnvironment env,
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext
        )
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // ===== Use Authentication ======
            app.UseAuthentication();

            // ===== Use MVC =====
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

**Create JWT Token Method**

```
// ===== Token =====
        private async Task<object> GenerateJwtToken(IdentityUser user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JwtExpireDays"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                claims,
                expires: expires,
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

Comment: Have you configured [JWT Bearer Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.0#jwt-bearer-authentication) in `ConfigureServices()`?

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Yes, I implemented JWT

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I edited question and added Startup.cs

Comment: Does the JWT passed in headers contain `roles` claim?

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I think no, how can i add it? I updated question and added CreateJWTToken method

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Yea, A added **new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")** and get Ok status. But how can i add multiple roles?

Comment: You need to add the same `ClaimTypes.Role` claim several times, once per each role.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I changed my **GenerateJwtToken()** method to add roles as a claims:

```
// Get User roles and add them to claims
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                AddRolesToClaims(claims, roles);

// ===== Token =====
        private async Task<object> GenerateJwtToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            };

            // Get User roles and add them to claims
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            AddRolesToClaims(claims, roles);

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JwtExpireDays"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                claims,
                expires: expires,
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }


        private void AddRolesToClaims(List<Claim> claims, IEnumerable<string> roles)
        {
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                var roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role);
                claims.Add(roleClaim);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can include your role name in the claims while generating the token ex :

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"The Role Of the logged in user, you can get from your DB")
            };
```

or You can use the Roles Object in the passed paramter then add the same above line.

```
 public class IdentityUser : IUser
    {
        public IdentityUser();
        public IdentityUser(string userName);

        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
        public virtual string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
        public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
        public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```