# Why am I forbidden if my User is associated to the required Role on my AspNetCore webapp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add Roles to my AspNet Core WebApp where authentication is already working fine.

Here is what I do in startup:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, Role, IdentityContext, Guid>>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role, IdentityContext, Guid>>();
```

I gave my `User` the previously created roles "Admin" and "SuperAdmin" and I added the following filter for a given controller action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

However, when trying to access that endpoint, I get a 403 forbidden.

I don't understand what I missed.

Comment: What about Users having "SuperAdmin" Role ?

Comment: What about them? Sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: Configuring Identity does not automatically make Authentication work.  What authentication are you using?

Comment: Authentication works. The only thing I added is the role in the authorize attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue similar to mine.
The person answered his own question but didn't mark it at as the answer.

Basically, it seems I have to add roles as claims in the JWT that I generate.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444865/1826096